# Duck Typing in Unity C# Scipt

Tags: unity-game-engine, duck-typing

In Unity3D C# script, access to Component involves GetComponent().

```
x = someGameObject.GetComponent<MyComponent>.field1;
```

In Unity3D Javascript, duck-type access to Component is allowed, like this:

```
x = someGameObject.field1;
```

Is there any way to access Component without calling GetComponent() in C# script too?

Comment: In  javascript if you have multiple components with the same field name, how do you tell them apart?

Answer (score 3):

> In Unity3D Javascript, duck-type access to Component is allowed, like this:

... no it isn't.

> Is there any way to access Component without calling GetComponent() in C# script too?

If you have a public or serialized MyComponent field that you assign using the inspector then you can access its members directly.

But otherwise no, to access the members of a component you need a reference to that component.